# How to update selected row in datagridview through textbox located on another form?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Hi guys i've been working so far with my system and it's almost done, but there is one thing i can't solve yet(not unless if you help me out).
so here's my code:

```
Private Sub btnEditmain_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditmain.Click

    Try
        editdgv()
        Form2.Show()
        DataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

here's the private sub editdgv

```
Private Sub editdgv()
    Dim i = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index

    With DataGridView2
        Form2.txtPeriod.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Rows(i).Cells("period").Value), " ", .Rows(i).Cells("period").Value)
        Form2.txtVouch.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Rows(i).Cells("vouch_amt").Value), " ", .Rows(i).Cells("vouch_amt").Value)
        Form2.txtIndivAmt.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Rows(i).Cells("individual_amt").Value), " ", .Rows(i).Cells("individual_amt").Value)
        Form2.txtCheckno.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Rows(i).Cells("check_no").Value), " ", .Rows(i).Cells("check_no").Value)
        Form2.txtDmailed.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Rows(i).Cells("D_MAILED").Value), " ", .Rows(i).Cells("D_MAILED").Value)
        Form2.txtDirno.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Rows(i).Cells("DIR_NO").Value), " ", .Rows(i).Cells("DIR_NO").Value)
        Form2.txtYrlvl.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Rows(i).Cells("year_student").Value), " ", .Rows(i).Cells("year_student").Value)
        Form2.txtUpdatedBy.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Rows(i).Cells("who_updated").Value), " ", .Rows(i).Cells("who_updated").Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

i was able to pass the value of the selected rows in datagridview to another form(textbox)
all things are working fine from there..

Now what i wanna do is to update that selected datagridview which is now in my textbox(s).
through a button click.

now i'm stuck at saving changes that i've done in the textbox, so it will be updated on the database.

pls help me on how to update the selected row in datagridview in textbox via button click.
thanks!

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: There are lot of solution to do that thing easily but, it is necessary to use proper method.So, I want to know that is your grid bound or unbound. means do you have assigned DataSource of DataGridView or it is manually input?

Comment: i assigned a data source from it. so it has a query then something like this Dim strcom2 As String = "select  period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO, who_updated, year_student from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY where CLAIM_NO like '" + txtClaimno.Text + "'"

                dt2.Clear()
                'Fill the data table with data from the database.
                Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(strcom2, connstr)
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt2)
                dataAdapter.Dispose()
                DataGridView2.DataSource = dt2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this code in notepad. So, it might have some issue.

```
FORM 1
Private Sub btnEditmain_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditmain.Click

   Try
        Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(DataGridView2.DataSource, DataTable)
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index)
        Dim frm As New Form2
        frm.dr = dr
        frm.Show()
        DataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


FORM 2

Public dr As DataRow = Nothing

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With dr
        txtPeriod.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("period")), vbNullString, .Item("period").ToString)
        txtVouch.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("vouch_amt")), vbNullString, .Item("vouch_amt").ToString)
        txtIndivAmt.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("individual_amt")), vbNullString, .Item("individual_amt").ToString)
        txtCheckno.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("check_no")), vbNullString, .Item("check_no").ToString)
        txtDmailed.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("D_MAILED")), vbNullString, .Item("D_MAILED").ToString)
        txtDirno.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("DIR_NO")), vbNullString, .Item("DIR_NO").ToString)
        txtYrlvl.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("year_student")), vbNullString, .Item("year_student").ToString)
        txtUpdatedBy.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("who_updated")), vbNullString, .Item("who_updated").ToString)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    With dr
        .Item("period") = txtPeriod.Text
        .Item("vouch_amt") = txtVouch.Text
        .Item("individual_amt") = txtIndivAmt.Text
        .Item("check_no") = txtCheckno.Text
        .Item("D_MAILED") = txtDmailed.Text
        .Item("DIR_NO") = txtDirno.Text
        .Item("year_student") = txtYrlvl.Text
        .Item("who_updated") = txtUpdatedBy.Text
    End With    
    dr.Table.AcceptChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: a lot of errors in the btneditmain. :/ one of them is the datarow dr

Comment: Sorry, there was a declaration issue. I have updated my code please take a look.

Comment: MissingMemberException was unhandled: Public member 'Value' on type 'String' not found. and the highlighted error was at this line  "txtPeriod.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("period").Value), vbNullString, .Item("period").Value)" there it is

Comment: Remove .Value after .Item("columnname")

Comment: still the same error.. i forgot to put an error tip. it says. "If you are attempting to access members on a late-bound object variable, make sure it is declared Public."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48536/discussion-between-nimesh-and-newbie-matt)